# Educational Volume Purchase and B2B (iOS apps)

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Can the [Educational Volume Purchase Program](http://www.apple.com/education/volume-purchase-program/) work with apps developed and distributed through the [B2B program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/)?  The WWDC session video on it mentioned education once, but it only talked specifically about distributing the apps through the [regular Volume Purchase Program](http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/), which requires a DUNS number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from telephone support: yes.  The B2B program interfaces with the Educational Volume Purchase Program the same way the regular Volume Purchase Program does.